# highcharts - Adding a seperate lines between the lines in categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a requirement which shows two different kinds of data as part of categories i.e adding a separate line between the bars.

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ye3Ak/2/)

I want to add a small line between A&B and between B&C with some data for example like below.

```
name: 'Staff Break Time',
intervals: [{ // From-To
from: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 12),
to: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 13)
},{ // From-To
from: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 16),
to: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 17)
}]
```

This should have a separate colors for ex: green & yellow.

I can add something like another equipment X, but this will be displayed as part of "UP" & "DOWN" bottom of the screen, but I don't want to do this as I'm not sure about this way whether it is correct. Sometimes it is overlapping with the actual bars.

Can you please suggest me the best way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Perhaps you can post an image of how you want it to look ?

Comment: Hi Steve,Thanks for your quick turn around. Below is the image url which I'm looking for. http://s5.postimg.org/kfwxsdbp3/example.jpg   where red bars are the one which i'm looking into. somehow I need to insert these red bars in between actual bars. Thanks Giri

Comment: Do you want to have these separation lines interactive (e.g. tooltip)? If not, utilize [`plotBands`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotBands).

Comment: ^ or plotLines may be less complicated.  OR, in fact, you could just format the axis gridLines.

Answer (score 0):

Example using formatting of y axis `gridLines`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Ye3Ak/229/

Though I would think that just adding a little bit of padding between each series would be a *FAR* more effective way to separate the categories, without adding unnecessary and distracting lines to the chart.

It also strikes me that a stacked bar chart, or an inverted columnrange chart, will be much easier ways to set up your data, FWIW.

Comment: Hi jlbriggs and all, thanks for your support and answer. Actually that was not a sepator kind of line. It basically represents the break time of employees. So the input to generate that line should be again time (from and to) similar to the equipments. Any thoughts about this? Many thanks,giri

Comment: Than how about using [`polygon`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.polygon) series type? Available since 4.1.0+ versions.

Comment: Giri - I think you'll need to provide a more detailed example then, as I am not seeing what you described in the example you posted...

Comment: Hi jilbriggs and pawel, Actually I'm looking for a graph which contain each machine's running modes based on time interval. ex. 9-11am automatic,11 am-3pm idle mode, 3-6pm fault mode etc. Like wise I have few machines, each machine has some operators (man power) so I would like to display the corresponding man power break time on button of each machine. For ex. 12-1pm is the lunch break and 5-5:15 pm tea break and all other time is working time..likewise I have to associate man power working hours and break time for each machine in the bottom of each machine as a line graph..thanks.Giri